# Find multiple exact words from a sentence in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

I want to find out if the following strings match one of my keywords.

- dallas/fort worth area - ‎stock at argo (false)
- dallas/fort worth area no stock at  argo (false)
- dallas, texas - ‎sales  at argo data resource (it says false)

  ```
  =IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("argo data resource corporation",A3)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("argodata",A3))),"true","")
  ```
- dallas/fort worth area - ‎research at argo data resource corporation
- plano, texas - ‎healthcare at argo data resource corporation

(same formula here it says true for these two)

I want to match a these words and if it exist partly or full it should consider it as true in the string..."argodata" or argo data resource corporation".

E.g. argo should be true instead it doesn't recognize it.

I tried the following formula:

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("argo data resource corporation",A3)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("argodata",A3))),"true","")

=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({"argo data resource corporation","argodata","tag3"},A1))),"YES","NO")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This is possible to do, at least in Excel, however it's very heavy in resources, therefore I suggest to split the sentence in words and use working columns to validate each word...

Answer (score 0):

yes, if argodata, or just argo or any combination with space or without space or part of it is in the string with other words, the formula should call it True.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this: `A$50`, change this to your range, working for me:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&B37&" ", " "&$A$2:$A$502&" ")))>0, TRUE, FALSE)
```